# Angular 8 : Error:(39, 9) TS2304: Cannot find name '*'. after closing WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I was working on an Angular project, after closing the IDE last night, I today that it doesn't recognise some libs like Int8Array, Int16Array, Int32Array... etc and many other libraries which seems a little strange to me!
actually, the project can run, but I still have erros like Error:(39, 9) TS2304: Cannot find name '*' and the IDE underline some methods in the code.
here is a screen shot:

[image]

Do you have an idea about this issue? thank you in advance

Comment: the errors come from Typescript compiler service; you have to inspect your `tsconfig.*.json` files to see what libraries are included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I forgot to say that I touched the **tsconfig.app.json** and I added some wrong lines 
[image]
The problem was solved... Thank you lena